# Load iframe if user scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm building a HTML website where I would like to load an iframe if the user scrolled nearly to the bottom. 
(The iframe contains a lot of JavaScript heavy *follow me* widgets that are slowing down the website if they would be loaded directly)

How can that be done?

Thanks. Uli

Comment: use google or the search textbox here. there are many many answers out there.

Comment: Hi Uli, Instead of using an iFrame why don't you just lazy load it when needed, perhaps using getscript(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.scroll()`

Like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == $(document).height()) {
       $('div').append('<iframe></iframe>');
   }
});​
```

Here's a fiddle with an example - http://jsfiddle.net/vRLsg/

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the position when you scroll

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
    if ($('body').scrollTop() == $('body').height()){
       loadIframe();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gWz3P/) - I guess it does what you need.